# Image disappeared when tapped on UIButton using ZFRippleButton library - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I am creating an sample app which integrated with library named `ZFRippleButton` . Now i am facing problem which when i tapped on button then image has been disappeared but when i take my finger out then the image is back as normal.

What is the problem?

Here is what i have done so far:

```
let button = ZFRippleButton()
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
button.rippleColor = UIColor.red
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
button.setTitle("File Server", for: .normal)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "filesharing"), for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "SFCompactText-Regular", size: 16)
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Here is its action:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fileShareButton), for: .touchUpInside)
@objc
func fileShareButton() {
    print("Doing some actions")
}
```

I cannot figure it out is that when i tapped on that button and then image has been disappeared and when i released my finger and image has appeared as usual. But title never disappear like image.

Can you solve me with this issue?